# Мне надо перевернуть двузначные числа массива не изменяя последовательность. Например: 25 71 84…, новый массив: 52 17 48…

Tags: javascript, html

Надо изменить разрядность цифр, образующих элементы исходного массива и, таким образом, сформировать новый массив.

```
var a = prompt("Enter a value");
var arr = [];

for (var i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
    arr[i] = a.charAt(i);
}
arr.reverse();
```

Этот код выводит 4,8, ,1,7, ,5,2

Answer (score 4):

Если числа двузначные, то не могу обойти стороной арифметическое решение:

```js
let arr = [37, 84, 92];
let rev = arr.map(v => 10 * v - 99 * ~~(v / 10));

console.log(arr, rev);
```

Comment: ничего себе. это круто :)

Answer (score 2):

```js
let a = "17 18 95"
  .split(' ')
  .map(m => [...m].reverse().join(''))
  .join(' ')
 
console.log(a)
```

Answer (score 1):

Мое решение:

```js
arr = [12,13,14]

for(let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    arr[i] = Number(String(arr[i]).split('').reverse().join(''));
}

console.log(arr)
```

Comment: Спасибо. Не знал о существовании снипета для выполнения кода.